Fix my Current Border Code - Include heading in border - Make edge bordering constant on all lines
I've got the point where I am happy with the horizontal lines and their locations. All borders are based off Column C/D (3/4) which adds line above from C-J and then ads a vertical line on that row.
I am wanting to extend the vertical border to all rows will cells in use. Make it look a bit tidier and also include the heading with a border the same as the others.
Currently I have this code - However I am new to any type of coding and managed to get here with some luck and a lot of testing. I am also looking to remove the line on row 36 I have no idea how its got there or why its there.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sheet as it Currently Stands
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Jobs") {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(null, null, null, null, false, false);
    var values = sheet.getRange(3, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
    var rangeList = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
      if (i > 0 && values[i - 1][0] != e[0] && e[0] != "") {
        ar.push("C" + (i + 3) + ":J" + (i + 3));
      }
      return ar;
    }, [])
    rangeList.push(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setBorder(true, true, null, true, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THIN);
  }
}


Consistent Border
Although I am not entirely certain that I could understand your expected result, the script below was written to check the conditions that you specified in your question like giving the header section the same border settings and removing an unwanted border on line 36 and lastly, setting the same border style on all row that has an occupied cell.
Code
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Jobs") {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBorder(null, null, null, null, false, false);
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    
    for (var row = 3; row <= lastRow; row++) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(row, 3, 1, 8);
      if (range.getValues()[0].some(cell => cell !== "")) {
        range.setBorder(true, true, null, true, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THIN);
      }
    }
  }
}

Sample Output

References: setBorder

Feel free to give feedback on the posted answer.

Thanks for the response, I did forget to mention, if there is a an empty description line I didn't want the line to be through it. I need empty cells to be groups with the used cells above. Such as Job 001 where there are 2 colours I need 2 lines. But I want the vertical lines to join.
Thanks for your help though.
